# How to I configure routing table for an interface like this?

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, interface

I have a vlan setup in my server with 2 VLANs

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens33.100
iface ens33.100 inet static
   address 172.16.1.13
   gateway 172.16.1.1
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   up route add -net 172.16.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.16.1.1
   vlan-raw-device ens33

auto ens33.300
iface ens33.300 inet static
   address 10.59.0.13
   gateway 10.59.0.1
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   up route add -net 10.59.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.59.0.1
   vlan-raw-device ens33
```

How to setup my routing table so that

1) All traffic to 10.59.0.0 goes through ens33.300 - gatway 10.59.0.1
2) All other traffic goes through ens33.100 - gateway 172.16.1.1

Ideally is it possible to have a routing table like this? I have been trying different things but not able to figure out.

```
10.59.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 10.59.0.1 ens33.300
172.16.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 172.16.1.1 ens33.100
0.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 172.16.1.1 ens33.100
```

Is this possible anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Routes to on-link hosts shouldn't have gateways. The only gateway that should be present in your example is the default gateway (the route to 0.0.0.0).